# "this" in jquery widget callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following widget

```
var a = $('#test').timetable({
            cell_click: openDialog
        });
```

whereby `cell_click` is an event generated by

```
_create:function(){ 
    dayBodyCells.click(function(){
            if( !$(this).hasClass('cell-inactive') ){
              var dic = self.getElementPos(this);
              self._trigger('cell_click', null,dic);        
        }
    });
```

and `openDialog` is the callback function. In the callback function for the `dayBodyCells`, i have `this` equaling the `td` element, which is what i expected. I'm curious - why does `this` inside function `openDialog` instead refers to `#test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a bound event handler (callback), `this` refers to the element on which the event was triggered. So:

```
$('#myid').click(function(){
    // this is the #myid element
})
```

In your code, dayBodyCells must be a td (as you expect) therefore `this` refers to it in the `click` handler. However, when you trigger the `cell_click` event, you must be firing it from the `#test` element (via `self._trigger`).

If `self._trigger('cell_click', null,dic)` were replaced with `$(this).trigger('cell_click', null,dic)`, `this` would then refer to the `td` within `openDialog`

Have a look at http://www.pkshiu.com/loft/archive/2009/01/understanding-this-this-and-event-in-a-jquery-callback-function and http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: u are right. I was indeed triggering from self, whihc is the widget itself.

Answer (score 0):

'Cause it just does?  The `this` of any function is established at call-time, and the contract of an event-handler is that `this` is set to the DOM element that had event, not the object in which the event-handler could be found.

Consider the following:

```
b = "DOG".toLowerCase
console.log(b());
```

You might think this would print out "dog", but no.  `toLowerCase` prints out the lower-case version of the String that `this` points to.  When a function is called like that, `this` is set to `undefined` so you get

```
TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
```

(At least one Firefox -- afaik, every browser will fail in some fashion.)

Your confusion might be that `this` seems vaguely like a lexically-bound variable.  It isn't, it's much closer to an ordinary function argument or the `arguments` list itself.